# jquery file upload cancel all uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for image upload for my website.

My code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $('#dropzone')
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    jqXHR = data;
});

$('button.cancel').click(function () {
jqXHR.abort();
});
```

When the user selects multiple files to upload, the cancel button only cancels 1 file upload instate of all files.

How can I have the cancel button to cancel all file uploads (in progress) once clicked?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

extracted from [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/290#issuecomment-10790239)

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function(e, data) {
         $('.progress_bar_wrapper').append($('.progress_context:first').clone());
        data.context = $('.progress_context:last');
        data.content.find('.abort').click(abortUpload );
        var xhr = data.submit();
        data.context.data('data',{jqXHR: xhr}); // so much data...
    }
)};

function abortUpload (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var template = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.template-upload'),
     data = template.data('data') || {}; // data, data , data (queue Monty Python skit)
      if (!data.jqXHR) {
        data.errorThrown = 'abort';
        this._trigger('fail', e, data);
      } else {
        data.jqXHR.abort();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there anyway not to use `var xhr = data.submit();` in the add function? Because putting that in will bypass the photo resize feature. I want the photo to be resized before being upload.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Stack to keep Track of uploads?

```
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    jqXHR.push(data);
});

$('button.cancel').click(function () {
    for (i=0; i < jqXHR.length; i++) { jqXHR[i].abort(); }
});
```